# Playback of rendered Video is skipping

Tags: animation

I run the preview the video and audio sync up without a problem. However, once I rendered it, the final video has lots of 1/2 second skips in both the video and audio. Like they are stuttering, but the audio and video do this in sync. Does anybody have any idea what could be causing that or supply a link to a tutorial that covers the output process in detail?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your encoding settings? This would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, it was the video player I was watching the final video on. I was using wondershare video, which is an excellent tool for those who have never used it, but for whatever reason it could play my video without skipping. Once i played it on windows media player and VLC it had so skipping issues. Hope this helps for anyone having this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Video playback is entirely dependent on the capacity of your computer to keep up with the data rate of the file. The fact that you are able to create a file does not mean that your computer can decode it and sustain the frame rate indicated on the video stream.

Some software is more efficient than others, try alternative programs to playback.

Be aware also that some files will never playback fluidly due to the low compression, codec efficiency, the amount of data to be processed, disk speed, or the ability of the hardware to buffer or decode in real time.